# Anatomically correct Sandworms

Tags: biology, creature-design, evolution, mythical-creatures

This is a submission for the [Anatomically Correct Series.](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series/2798#2798)
[image: Sandwurm from Magic: The Gathering]

Sandworms are a famous creature in fiction and mythology. Various mythological creatures are the Mongolian Death Worm and the Lambton Worm. For fiction, the movie Tremors is about Sandworms and Dune has the largest and most famous Sandworms.

The largest worm on Earth weighs less than 2 kg so it would be strange for a worm to grow to a massive size. I'm also not sure what a giant worm would eat. It might actually make more sense for a huge worm to evolve from snakes rather than other worms.

Anyway, is it plausible for there to be a huge wormlike creature that lives in the desert and tunnels underground?

Comment: We don't admit questions about third party worlds.

Comment: All you need to do to make it on-topic is to take out all references to commercial products (i.e. Dune, Tremours etc.,) then describe in detail the environment and characteristics you want - of a cited mythical creature.

Comment: @L.Dutch "Various mythological creatures"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about a 3rd party work and not about a mythological creature.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, what would it feed on? When it comes to water, it is possible it could find enough underground, though you have to ask how deep the tunnels would be since there needs to also be enough water for civilizations above the sand and native plants and animals.

Feeding on travelers is possible but it cannot be its main food source.
One thing to consider is that with an organism of that size, it cannot be in a constant state of activity. That would simply demand too much energy, bringing us back to the issue of food.

Instead, it would likely spend most of its time in hibernation, and only be awake during mating season, when it needs to eat or drink, and its occasional desire to surface and check on how things are faring above ground.